# trouble installing 16.04-system installation

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, system

When trying to install 16.04, I get a message that I have 3 broken packages that need to be fixed but when I click on Fix Broken Packages I get an error message saying I have "held packages". Point is, how do I go about installing the new upgrade and fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn off all the extra ppas you might have added before the upgrade?  Did you remove the hold on the packages which are "held"?
For example:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold package_name
```

see [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) for other package managers.

---

Yes assuming dbus is the first package to unhold.

Comment: I have 4 packages held so, per your example would I type sudo apt-mark unhold dbus in the command line for each package ?